# Um método pegar informações de outro método

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Olá, gostaria de uma ajuda. Estou refazendo a apostila de java orientado a objetos da caelum e veio uma dúvida que gostaria de uma ajuda.

Na apostila pede para criar um sistema simples de um um banco. Indo direto ao assunto, foi criada uma classe conta que possui atributos como o nome do cliente, saldo limite essas coisas. Possui o método `sacar` (possui retorno do tipo `boolean`, pois verifica o saldo do cliente na hora de sacar), deposita e transferir.

Eu criei um método chamado `extrato` no qual mostra o nome do dono da conta, o saldo e as operações que ele fez. Eu gostaria que ele pegasse um `boolean` do método `saca` e imprimir uma mensagem, baseado nessa informação.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
public class Conta{
  int numero;
  String dono;
  double saldo;
  double limite;

  //métodos
  boolean saca(double valor) {
        if (this.saldo < valor) {          
            return false;
    } else {
        this.saldo = this.saldo - valor;        
        return true;
    }
  }
    void deposita(double quantidade) {
        this.saldo += quantidade;
 }
 boolean transfere(Conta destino, double valor) {
   boolean retirou = this.saca(valor);
   if (retirou == false) {
     // não deu pra sacar!
     return false;
   } else {
     destino.deposita(valor);
     return true;
   }
}

 void extrato(){
   System.out.println("Nome do Cliente: " +this.dono);
   if(this.saca(valor) == true){
    System.out.println("Saque de "+this.dono+" realizado com Sucesso!!!");
   } else{
    System.out.println("Saldo de "+this.dono+" está Insuficiente");
   }

   System.out.println("Saldo atual: " +this.saldo);
 }
}
```

```
public class Programa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Conta minhaConta = new Conta();
    Conta minhaConta2 = new Conta();
    minhaConta.dono = "Daniel Araújo";
    minhaConta2.dono = "Maria Araújo";
    minhaConta.saldo = 1000.0;
    minhaConta2.saldo = 1500.0;
    // saca 200 reais
    minhaConta.saca(2000);
    minhaConta2.saca(300);
    // deposita 500 reais
    minhaConta.deposita(500);
    minhaConta2.deposita(100);
    //transfere
    minhaConta.transfere(minhaConta2, 250);
    minhaConta.extrato();
    minhaConta2.extrato();
    }
}
```

[Link do github do pequeno projeto](https://github.com/Pakato14/DuvidaJava/blob/master/Conta.java)

Comment: O seu código tem vários vícios de linguagem (péssima identação, `== true` e `== false`, esqueceu o modificador `private` nos campos e `public` nos métodos, etc.) mas a estrutura dele é plausível ao que ele se propõe. Entretanto, não ficou claro para mim uma coisa: **Qual é a sua dúvida afinal? O que é que você está perguntando? Que tipo de ajuda você quer com esse código?**

Comment: Sei que está cheio de erros, mas era uma duvida simples que um amigo aqui respondeu. Esse não era um projeto sério, era apenas uma duvida que surgiu nos meus estudos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma lista para armazenar as operações realizadas segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Conta {

    int numero;
    String dono;
    double saldo;
    double limite;
    List<String> operacoesRealizadas = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Conta minhaConta = new Conta();
        Conta minhaConta2 = new Conta();
        minhaConta.dono = "Daniel Araújo";
        minhaConta2.dono = "Maria Araújo";
        minhaConta.saldo = 1000.0;
        minhaConta2.saldo = 1500.0;
        // saca 200 reais
        minhaConta.saca(2000);
        minhaConta2.saca(300);
        // deposita 500 reais
        minhaConta.deposita(500);
        minhaConta2.deposita(100);
        //transfere
        minhaConta.transfere(minhaConta2, 250);
        minhaConta.extrato();
        minhaConta2.extrato();
    }

    //métodos
    boolean saca(double valor) {
        if (this.saldo < valor) {
            return false;
        } else {
            this.saldo = this.saldo - valor;
            operacoesRealizadas.add("Saque de R$: " + valor + " Realizado");
            return true;
        }
    }

    void deposita(double quantidade) {
        this.saldo += quantidade;
        operacoesRealizadas.add("Deposito de R$: " + quantidade + " Realizado");
    }

    boolean transfere(Conta destino, double valor) {
        boolean retirou = this.saca(valor);
        if (retirou == false) {
            // não deu pra sacar!
            return false;
        } else {
            destino.deposita(valor);
            operacoesRealizadas.add("Transferencia de R$: " + valor + " Realizado");
            return true;
        }
    }

    void extrato() {
        System.out.println("Nome do Cliente: " + this.dono);
        for (int i = 0; i < operacoesRealizadas.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("" + operacoesRealizadas.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Saldo atual: " + this.saldo);
    }
}
```